# Updating buffer objects without memory leak

Tags: opengl

i want to update VBO storage with other data, so i want previous storage not to leak. I can't use `glMapBuffer` as my size of data would be changing. So if I call again `glBufferData` with new size and data, does it allocate new storage ? what happens with previous memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OpenGL specification:

> `BufferData` [...] delete[s] any existing data store ...